# map method function javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, methods, trim

hello to every one i hope you have a good day :)

i need to define a function, It should accept an array of strings which may contain additional space characters.

the function should use the array map method in order to make a new array full of trimmed names.

i tried something like that but its not close to work unfortunately

```
function cleanNames(array) {
   const trimArray = array.map() function() {
     return array.trim();
   }
}
```

Comment: The callback should get the string, and you should pass the string to trim.
You also forgot to return `trimArray`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 2):

Your code throws the following syntax error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'function'

in `array.map() function() {`

You have to trim the names inside the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) callback function. You can also use arrow function ([`=>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)) syntax to shorten the code:

```js
function cleanNames(arr) {
  return arr.map(i => i.trim());
}

console.log(cleanNames(['John ', ' Jane', ' Joe ']));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this:

```
var array = [" Mike", " Hellen", "Robert "];
array = array.map(function (el) {
  return el.trim();
});
console.log(array);
```

you have to do the edit in map function.

Answer (score 1):

```js
 function cleanNames(input) {
   return input.map(val => val.trim());
}
const names = [" Joy ", " James", "Raj"];
console.log(cleanNames(names));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log([" Mike", " Hellen", "Robert "].map(name => name.trim()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try and make the minimum amount of code:

```
[' aa ', ' b b ', '   c c '].map(i=>i.trim());
```

This will solve your problem.

By the way, if you are using jQuery the syntax is a bit different and even simpler:

```
$.map([' aa ', ' bb ', '   cc '], $.trim);
```